# Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi 7.0.0 is not compatible with net70

Tags: .net-core, nuget-package

I'm trying to set up a .net project.
when I run `dotnet build` I get the following error:

```
C:\Projects\Map\Map\src\api\api.csproj : error NU1202: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi 7.0.0 is not compatible with net70 (.NETFramework,Version=v7.0) / win7 
-x86. Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi 7.0.0 supports: net7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0)

C:\Projects\Map\Map\src> dotnet --version
7.0.200
```

I downloaded and installed dotnet 7.0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `net70 (.NETFramework,Version=v7.0)`? I don't think it's a thing.

Comment: Can you provide the contents of the `api.csproj`?

Comment: @VladDX, please:


`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="7.0.0" />`

Comment: There is not enough info to help you. You need to provide more context. Ideally, the way to reproduce your problem.